# On Elkies' $\text{9T32}$ nonic and a shared property with j-function formulas

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, galois-theory, number-fields

**I. First Set**

Before going to Elkies' nonic, we start with something a bit simpler. There is a list of j-function formulas in this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4580319/4781). For example, for prime levels $p = 5,7,13,$ we have,

$$j=\frac{(x^2+10x+5)^3}x$$
$$j=\frac{(x^2+5x+1)^3(x^2+13x+49)}x$$
$$j=\frac{(x^4+7x^3+20x^2+19x+1)^3(x^2+5x+13)}x$$

Assume $j$ as **any** number, hence a free parameter. Then these equations have groups $\text{PGL}(2,5), \text{PGL}(2,7), \text{PGL}(2,13),$ respectively, so generally is not solvable in radicals. However, $x$ is solvable if $j$ is the $j$-function **OR** if we do this,

$$\frac{(x^2+10x+5)^3}x =\frac{(n^2+10n+5)^3}n$$

for **any** non-zero $n$. For example, let $n=2$,

$$\frac{(x^2+10x+5)^3}x =\frac{29^3}2$$

Its irreducible $5$th-deg factor has Frobenius group $F(5)=4\times5=20$ hence is now solvable. Likewise for its higher siblings which have $F(7)=6\times7=42$ and $F(13)=12\times13=156$.

**Edit** (May 3): For an example where the result is **non-solvable**, let

$$j = \frac{(x + 432)(x^2 + 80x - 3888)^3}{7^7 x^3}$$

which has familiar discriminant (without its numerical factors) as $D = -(j-1728)^3\, j^4$. Then,

$$\frac{(x + 432)(x^2 + 80x - 3888)^3}{x^3} = \frac{(n + 432)(n^2 + 80n - 3888)^3}{n^3}$$

does **not** yield a solvable sextic factor.

**Q:** So the procedure doesn't work on just any rational function. What condition should be satisfied such that the procedure yields a solvable factor?

---

**II. Second Set**

Searching the literature for similar "formulas", the paper *[Galois Number Fields with Small Root Discriminant](http://cda.morris.umn.edu/%7Eroberts/dpr/Research_files/lowgrd.pdf)* by J. Jones and D. Roberts was a gold mine. They had degrees for $p \leq 10$ and even for $p=17$ which I mentioned in an old [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226449/whats-so-special-about-these-17th-deg-equations). But this equating of,

$$P(j,x) = P(j,n)$$

was not there. A small sample for deg 9,

$$j = \frac{(x^3 + 4x^2 + 10x + 6)^3}{(4x^2 + 13x + 32)}$$

Again, assume $j$ as a free parameter. This equation in Magma notation is $\text{9T32}$ and has order $9\times12\times14 = 1512$ (unsolvable). However,

$$\frac{(x^3 + 4x^2 + 10x + 6)^3}{(4x^2 + 13x + 32)} = \frac{(n^3 + 4n^2 + 10n + 6)^3}{(4n^2 + 13n + 32)}$$

(after removing the linear factor) is $\text{8T36}$ and has order $12\times14 = 168$ (solvable). Elkies' nonic is also $\text{9T32}$ but a bit trickier,

$$j^2+(9x^4 - 42x^3 - 675x^2 - 1485x - 441)j - (x^3 - 9x^2 - 69x - 123)^3 =0$$
$$j^2+(9n^4 - 42n^3 - 675n^2 - 1485n - 441)j - (n^3 - 9n^2 - 69n - 123)^3 =0$$

Eliminating $j$ between the two using resultants and getting rid of two linear factors yields a $16$-deg equation with order $12\times14\times16 = 2688$ (and solvable according to Magma).

**Note:** For consistency, I still used the variable $j$ for the second set, but they are not to be understood as level-9 formulas for the j-function.

---

**III. Question**

So why is it for these two sets (and some others) that eliminating the common variable $j$ between $P(j,x) = P(j,n) = 0$ suddenly yields a parametric equation with a solvable Galois group?

Comment: Your first part doesn't makes sense without some other info/definitions.  I assumed j was the j-function, but then you say: if j is the j-function?

Comment: @Kimball I made some edits to clarify. Feel free to ask if further editing is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has relatively little to do with the j-invariant itself. If you take any rational function $f(x)\in k(x)$ and let $G:=Gal(f(x) - t/k(t))$ (also referred to as the monodromy group of $f$), then by elementary Galois theory, $Gal(f(x)-f(y) / k(y))$ is a point stabilizer in $G$ (in the usual action on the roots). In your cases $G$ is $P\Gamma L_2(q)$ acting on $q+1$ points ($q=5,7,8,13$) which has solvable point stabilizer.

(Edit: Of course the reason why this observation "wasn't there" in the linked Jones/Roberts paper is that this is comparatively the "trivial case", working for every $f$. More interesting are the (exceptional) cases where a group is a monodromy group of two essentially *different* rational functions in the same Galois closure, which then gives shrinking of $Gal(f(x)-g(y)/k(y))$ in the analogous way - the sextic above together with the right quintic (relates to the $j$-invariant) is one such pair.)

Comment: I first noticed the phenomenon when looking at j-function formulas and the fact they have predictable Galois groups helped. I knew it couldn't be unique to those formulas, but didn't know what was the necessary condition. So I made an edit to the post to give an example when the procedure doesn't work.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII The example in the edit has monodromy group $S_7$ (quickly seen from the multiplicities 3 and 4 of the two poles, since this yields a transitive group with an element of cycle type (3.4)), and that has nonsolvable point stabilizer $S_6$. For the same reason, a "generic" rational function of degree $>5$ doesn't work since it will have symmetric monodromy group. I'm not sure if your question is whether the solvability of the point stabilizer can be read of just from things like the factorization pattern of the function - in general one would need to dig a bit deeper.

Comment: I had tested all the "formulas" in the Jones/Roberts paper and, if I remember correctly, ALL passed the test. (Even the 17-deg yielded a solvable 16-deg.) They must have used a uniform guiding principle to generate those formulas. (The example in the edit was from another paper.)

Comment: Jones/Roberts are interested in extensions with particular Galois groups, in particular certain almost simple groups (which they mention explicitly). It's not surprising that for a small almost-simple group the point stabilizer in a certain action is often solvable and then $Gal(f(x) - g(y))$ will come out solvable as a side effect - the techniques for computing these functions though have nothing to do with solvability issues. (There are also exceptions of course, e.g. there are degree-11 rational functions with group $PSL_2(11)$, and here the point stabilizer $A_5$ is nonsolvable).

Comment: I see. One side-effect of my focus on the j-function re their work was I accidentally noticed an equation/formula in their paper that was NOT for the j-function, but for another modular function entirely. With the help of Mathematica, I found several other members of the family, but it is not yet complete for now. More stuff to explore.